# Android Studio 3.3 Gradle Issue: Invalid LOC Header (bad signature)?

Tags: macos, android-studio

So I have the following error in Android Studio 3.3 on MacOS 10.13.6:

Gradle Sync Issues: Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature).

Here's the thing... It's a fresh install... I have no idea what to do as I've never come across this before.

Comment: Hi , Did u solve this issue.? Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem on this process

first, you need to be close android studio then
find them ."gradle" folder then enter the "wrapper" then enter the "dists" after entering the "dists" folder you look like "gradle-X.X-all" 
then you move or delete "gradle-X.X-all" all file from "dists" folder then reopen android studio and enjoy it.

This process 100% working for me